# Use XBox 360 controller on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, game-controller

How to use a wired USB Xbox 360 gamepad on Mac OS X 10.10.5?

Many sites refer to [d235j's 360Controller-n releases](https://github.com/d235j/360Controller-n/releases) but there are no downloads available

I installed [Tattiebogle's 360ControllerInstall](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver#toc1) but installing and restarting had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the terminal.

   Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
2. Install `brew` if you don't have it yet.

   Write in the Terminal app:

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask 2> /dev/null
   ```

   and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
3. Use `brew` to install `xbox360-controller-driver`.

   ```
   brew cask install xbox360-controller-driver
   ```

   The controller will start working without restart. You might have to disconnect and reconnect the controller and to restart the game using it.

Many thanks to [macappstore.org's post](http://macappstore.org/xbox360-controller-driver/) for providing the solution.

Comment: `brew cask install xbox360-controller-driver
Error: No available Cask for xbox360-controller-driver
Error: nothing to install`
:'( but it should be [available here](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver) but looks like this one is [more maintained](https://github.com/360Controller/360Controller)